# Method of replacing a FULL LINE with text in a file?

Tags: replace, vbscript

I'm looking for a way to replace a FULL LINE OF TEXT in a text file using VBScript. I've managed to get my code to find the line I want and replace some text in it, but as I said, I want the full line to be replaced.

```
'Finds and Replaces some text in a file using line numbers
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

strFileName = WScript.Arguments(0)
n = WScript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = WScript.Arguments(2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFSO.CreateTextFile "temp"

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)

For i = 1 to 37
    If i < n Then
        before = objFile.ReadLine
        Call oldText
    ElseIf i = n Then
        current = objFile.ReadLine
        Call currentText
    ElseIf i > n Then
        after = objFile.ReadLine
        Call newText
    End If
Next

Sub oldText
    Set objTemp = objFSO.OpenTextFile("temp", 8) 'Open Text file for appending
    objTemp.WriteLine before
    objTemp.Close
End Sub

Sub currentText

    ' ########################################################################
    ' This is where my problem is - I don't know how to replace the whole line
    ' with my strNewText variable. As seen below - I'm not that familiar with
    ' VBScript, so I done a little tinkering:
    ' ########################################################################

    'change = Replace(current,  , strNewText) 'won't change anything
    'change = Replace(current, "" , strNewText) 'won't change anything
    'change = Replace(current, strNewText) 'won't change anything either
    'change = Replace(current.all, strNewText) 'nope
    'change = Replace(current, current, strNewText) 'no-dice=veryTrue

    'This works but only for where "block" appears in the line. I haz full
    'line plz?
    change = Replace(current, "block", strNewText)

    Set objTemp = objFSO.OpenTextFile("temp", 8)
    objTemp.WriteLine change
    objTemp.Close
End Sub

Sub newText
    Set objTemp = objFSO.OpenTextFile("temp", 8)
    objTemp.WriteLine after
    objTemp.Close
End Sub

objFSO.CopyFile "temp", strFileName, True

'objFSO.DeleteFile "temp"
```

For testing purposes I've commented out the deletion of the temp file so I can check and see if the changes have actually been made.

Another method I chose was, if a certain file was specified, to copy a source file with pre-made changes into the same destination of the target file (overwriting it, just like the temp file would). The code for this is as follows:

```
strFileName = WScript.Arguments(0)
n = CLng(WScript.Arguments(1))
strNewText = WScript.Arguments(2) 'This is also used as the folder name when changing eula. Just need to rename variable to something more readable.
tempFileName = "temp"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTemp = objFSO.OpenTextFile(tempFileName, 2, True)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName)

If strFileName = "eula.txt" Then
    objFSO.CopyFile "sourc file path\eula.txt", "C:root folder\"+strNewText+"\eula.txt", True 'Paths are typed in actual code.
Else
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        If objFile.Line = n Then
            objTemp.WriteLine strNewText
        Else
            objTemp.WriteLine objFile.ReadLine
        End If
    Loop

    objFile.Close
    objTemp.Close

    objFSO.CopyFile tempFileName, strFileName, True
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to replace anything. Just write `strNewText` instead of `current` to the output file. If you need to make that depend on whether the line from the input file contains a particular (sub)string you can use an `If` condition:

```
If InStr(current, "block") > 0 Then
  objTemp.WriteLine strNewText
Else
  objTemp.WriteLine current
End If
```

Some other things I'd recommend:

- Opening and closing files is expensive. Don't do that over and over again. Open the output file just once before your loop, and close it after everything is written.
- Process the input file with a `Do Until` loop so you don't need to know the exact number of lines.
- If you need to check a particular line number you can use the [`Line`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsfhd43.aspx) property of the file object, which has the number of the line that will be read next, instead of keeping an index yourself.

Modified code:

```
strFileName = WScript.Arguments(0)
n = CLng(WScript.Arguments(1))
strNewText = WScript.Arguments(2)
tempFileName = "temp"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'create temp file and open for writing
Set objTemp = objFSO.OpenTextFile(tempFileName, 2, True)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    If objFile.Line = n Then
        current = objFile.ReadLine
        If InStr(current, "block") > 0 Then
            objTemp.WriteLine strNewText
        Else
            objTemp.WriteLine current
        End If
    Else
        objTemp.WriteLine objFile.ReadLine
    End If
Loop

objFile.Close
objTemp.Close

objFSO.CopyFile tempFileName, strFileName, True
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Asgar! I've taken on board your suggestions and tried to code it without copying (so I could learn it easier) but I started to run into problems and eventually copied exactly what you had given into a separate .vbs file to no avail. When ran from the Command Line, the script will run and it will finish. In the Command Window it looks fine. But when I check the file - no changes have been made. I checked the temp file too and the changes have not been made there either. I done some modifications to the code to test it out and gather what the problem was. Continued...

Comment: First of all, I tried adding the parameter 'for Reading' in `Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, True)` so it became `Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, 1, True)`. I also tried changing the condition in the If Statement checking for a substring to `If InStr(current, "block") = 0 Then`, essentially bypassing the condition (I thought). However, this still doesn't work.

Comment: In the Else statement, of the same If block of code above, I changed the variable to write to the temp file from `objTemp.WriteLine objFile.ReadLine` to `objTemp.WriteLine current`, just to see if it made any difference. It didn't.

If I'm missing anything, let me know - but I'm trying to remain patient with this! lol

Again, thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @whiteside0013 Sorry, my mistake. The second argument (the line number) must be cast to an integer, otherwise checking the line number won't work correctly (because an integer 2 and a string "2" are not equal). Fixed.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sorry for the late reply! Again, thanks for the help! Although, I tried to implement what you put above and the same would happen - temp file is created, but the correction doesn't take place in it. For some reason it won't replace the line with anything. I will say though, I did get a little impatient and try to go about this another way. I had a source file with pre-made changes that I would copy into the place of the target file to be changed. This doesn't work either. For some reason my code isn't over-writing the file, but no errors etc.

Comment: I will add the new code for the above method at the end of the code in the question - The layout isn't as desirable in the comments.

Comment: @whiteside0013 I tested with the exact code from my answer, and it worked just fine. Please provide evidence. Do not post code in comments, but edit your question. Include sample input as well. Also see that you get the replacement working first before you add other stuff/conditions around it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have put your code in a separate file and the only thing I have changed is the line where it checks for a sub string to check for "eula" rather than "block". I saved it in the same folder as my target file to remove any complications of file paths. I ran it from the Windows Command Prompt and the output was the following: 

`C:\Users\conner\Desktop\Minecraft\Test>Ansgar.vbs "eula.txt" 4 "eula=true"

C:\Users\conner\Desktop\Minecraft\Test>`

After checking the target file "eula.txt", the change was not made.
Line 4 of the eula file read "eula=false" and nothing else.

Comment: Ummm... yeah. Because your code only replaces anything if the filename is *NOT* "eula.txt".

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Seriously... Okay, I know the site isn't meant for teaching the basics per se, but do you mind explaining why this is? Sorry about this!

Comment: It's because you put in a condition that copies the file if the filename is "eula.txt" and does the replacement if it's not, obviously. What did you expect `If strFileName = "eula.txt" Then ... Else ... End If` to do?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  Oh, I set up another file with the same name with pre-made changes. The "eula.txt" was an exception to other files. If it's "eula.txt" it was supposed to copy the pre-made file in the place of the target eula file. Which it doesn't do for some reason.

Comment: Most likely because your code opens the file before you get to the copying part. Files with open handles to them can't be replaced.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers The only file with the open handle on it before the If statement is the "temp" file, which isn't used when it comes to replacing "eula.txt". I don't have any `objFSO.OpenTextFile` where "eula.txt" is concerned.

Comment: That may be, but this is getting *way* off the topic of your question. Please ask a new question if you need further help with that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Okay, I'll look into it, Thanks for your help!.